# Is it correct to write the range of the sigmoid function as $[0, 1]$?

Tags: functions

The sigmoid function is defined as follows:

$$\sigma (z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}.$$

Hence, $\sigma (z) = 0$ when $z$ is minus infinity, and $\sigma (z) = 1$ when $z$ is infinity.

Why is the range of the sigmoid function written as $[0, 1]$ instead of $(0, 1)$ in [some lectures](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/5.pdf#section.5.1)?

And the same thing goes for the tanh function.

Comment: Many lectures on applied mathematics do not aim for mathematical rigour. Thus, they may not want to distinguish between [0,1] and (0,1). As in real-life applications, it doesn't matter. For example, you can argue that $\sigma(-100) = 0$ in 99.9999% of the usecases.

Comment: In the notes you linked to, I think they just weren't being super careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect some uses are a [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) specification, for example, 
$$  \sigma: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]: z \mapsto \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-z}}  \text{.}  $$
It is only required that the range of the function be a subset of the codomain.

Other uses, I suspect, are consequence of the fact that real analysis typically takes place on the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), which is $\Bbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$, with the expected order and some arithmetic of the infinities defined.  (But not all arithmetic; $\infty + (-\infty)$ is not defined.)  Much rigorous statistics starts in real analysis, so it is not unusual to see the extended real line sneak into other parts of statistics.